# Save and display form values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I need to save the filled in form values in a JSON and then display the same on click of button.

I have saved the initial entries filled in but not able to pull up values saved through `ng-repeat`.

Here is the code.

```
<html ng-app="formList">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Day 7 Angular Workaround</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css">
<script src="js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div class="container">

    <form id="form" method="post" action="post.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="fname">First name</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="First Name"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="lname">Surname</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Surname"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><label>Gender</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male" checked>
                    Male
                  </label>
                </div>

                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female">
                    Female
                  </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
           <div class="col-sm-3"> <label>Marital Status</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="radio">
                    <label>
                     <input type="radio" name="marital" id="married" value="married" checked onchange="spouseField()">
                    Married
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="marital" id="unmarried" value="unmarried" onchange="spouseField()">
                    UnMarried
                  </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="spouse-name">Name of Spouse</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="spouse-name" name="spouse-name" placeholder="Spouse name"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-3"><label for="other">Other Details</label></div>
            <div class="col-sm-9"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="other" name="other" placeholder="Enter Other Details..."></div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default" id="reset">Reset</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" ng-click="showResults=true">Save &amp; Show</button>
            <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="show" ng-click="showValues();">Hide</button> -->

        </div>
    </form> 


    <div id="showResults" ng-show="showResults" >
        <table class="table-responsive table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Firstname</th>
                <th>LastName</th>
                <th>Other Details</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="item in formElements">

                <td>{{item.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.other}}</td>
                <td>{{item.gender}}</td>

            </tr>


        </table>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var fname = document.getElementById('fname'); 
        var lname = document.getElementById('lname'); 
        var button = document.getElementById("submit");
        var spouseName = document.getElementById('spouse-name'); 
        var other = document.getElementById('other'); 
        var marital = document.getElementsByName('marital');
        var gender = document.getElementsByName('gender');


        var formValues = {};

        button.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            validateForm();

            return false;
         }); 


        //set focus

        fname.focus();


        //set spouse text field behaviour



        function spouseField(){

            // var marital = document.getElementsByName('marital');


            var marital_value;


            for(var i = 0; i < marital.length; i++){
                    if(marital[i].checked){
                        marital_value = marital[i].value;
                    }
                }

                if(marital_value ==="married"){

                    spouseName.disabled =  false;
                }
                else {
                    spouseName.disabled =  true;
                }
        }


        //empty fields check


        function validateForm(){

                var inputs = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName("input");

                 for (var i = 0; i<inputs.length; i++){
                    if (!inputs[i].value && inputs[i].disabled === false ){

                        alert( inputs[i].placeholder + " can not be empty.");
                        inputs[i].focus();
                         return false;
                     }

                 }

                 // check for empty spaces on name and spouse name
                    if( fname.value.trim().length == 0 || lname.value.trim().length == 0 || (spouseName.value.trim().length == 0 && spouseName.disabled ===  false) ){
                        alert("Empty spaces in name fields not allowed");
                        return false;
                    }

                saveValues();
                // showValues();
             // alert("Thank you !");
        }

        function saveValues(){



            formValues.firstName =  fname.value;


            formValues.lastName = lname.value; 


            formValues.other = other.value;


            formValues.gender = (function genderValue(){
                for (var i = 0, length = gender.length; i < length; i++) {
                    if (gender[i].checked) {

                        return gender[i].value;

                    }
                }
            })();


            return formValues;

        }



 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
var app = angular.module("formList", []);
 app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
 $scope.formElements = formValues;

});
```

Comment: Where have you defined the formValues? Are you getting it from some service?

Comment: formValues is an object being formed from the form's filled-in fields. It's there in the bottom script of main page under the function saveValues

Comment: There's nothing "Angular" about your code except the ng-repeat. I would suggest you read up on docs around ng-model and how to use it on form fields. And also ng-click.

Comment: @codemonkey I am kind of getting started with it. I think you are hinting about two way data binding to display the labels and other attributes of form. What's the solution for now given this code ? or how can one modify it to implement the two way binding. This can be a perfect example for me to start. I feel confused to implement it as the formElements of scope is not even accessible to me results div.

Answer (score 0):

Angular is not very tolerant of code written that is not written in the "angular" way.  The specific problem here is probably that nothing is triggering the Angular  digest cycle, which would normally happen automatically with the use of ng-model, ng-click, etc.

The simplest way to fix this code would be to add a function to your controller to call validateForm and call it using ng-click on your submit button.  But be aware that you are setting yourself up for unending pain if you don't go back to square one and write the whole thing as a proper Angular application.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @ChrisRibe. The digest cycle is the problem in this piece of code, but you are much better of just converting your code entirely to Angular. It's not a great idea to mix Angular with non-Angular.

And if you are doing this as a learning exercise, it's best to learn to do it right.

For this code, I would suggest creating an object like `$scope.person` or some such thing. Then use ng-model to bind all your form values to `person.whatever`. You can then get rid of almost everything except `validateValues` from your JS code.
Call `validateValues` on ng-click of your button.

Read up a few tutorials, and follow the "Angular" way for less pain.